# Best Browser for Editing Posts

Tags: tinymce, editor, visual-editor, bug, browser-compatibility

What browser is best supported by Wordpress.org for editing posts in the visual editor (which I guess is TinyMCE)?

I use Google Chrome and have run into issues which are specific to just this browser. Here's an [example bug](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17154).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE is generally cross-browser compatible. However they provide the best support for IE, Firefox and Safari. I've never ran into problems with my beloved Opera too.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Browser_compatiblity

If there are any bugs they're mostly not browser-dependent, but if they are - try Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE - in that order.